# Vite dev server: Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "vue". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../"

Tags: vuejs3, vite

I'm using a Vue3 library I've created to import components into an HTML page. It works fine if I compile the library and `<script>` include the compiled es library assets using an `importmap`.

In development I'd like to run vite as a dev server (`npx vite`) and have it serve the library's components dynamically. The example I've seen of this setup in the Vite documents seem to be serving a Vue App https://vitejs.dev/guide/backend-integration.html#backend-integration

Here's the relevant part of my `index.html`:

```
...
<div id="counter"></div>
...
<script type="importmap">
  { "imports": {
      "my-lib": "http://localhost:4000/src/index.ts",
      } 
  }
</script>
<script type="module" src="http://localhost:4000/@vite/client"></script>
<script type="module">
  import { createApp } from 'vue';
  import { Counter } from 'my-lib';   
  createApp(Counter).mount('#counter');
</script>
```

I'm getting this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "vue". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".
```

It is coming from my `src/index.ts` file which is the input to building the library.
It is served from the vite dev server with this content:

```
import Counter from "/src/components/Counter.vue";
export { Counter };
```

Is there some configuration change I need to make to my `vite.config.ts` or does `@vite/client` not support this configuration?

I don't know if this is related to the error, but if I request Counter.vue from my vite server: at `http://localhost:4000/src/components/Counter.vue`

I get this error in the browser:
`Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module`

It is referring to `import { ref } from 'vue'` in Counter.vue:

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref } from 'vue'

const count = ref(0)
</script>

<template>
  <button @click="count++">You've clicked me {{ count }} times</button>
</template>

<style scoped>
button {
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: lightblue;
}
</style>
```

(though maybe that is due to the browser not processing the file as it would when loading a module script)